# How to get username/userID in slack bot

Tags: slack-api, slack

https://github.com/DeronLee/starbot.git

I created a slack bot and it worked fine. But when somebody sends message to the bot,  I'm not able to tell who sent it.

I tried `msg.user msg.username`, but all of them are undefined.

I just want my output to look like this

```
abc: @starbot hello
starbot: hello. abc
```

finally. I got it.

```
    slack.users.info({
    token: config('SLACK_TOKEN'),
    user: msg.user
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    var text = makeMessage.makeMessage(msg.text, data.user.name);
    sendMessage.send(msg, text, slack);
```

Comment: If you have solved the question, post the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
slack.users.info({
  token: config('SLACK_TOKEN'),
  user: msg.user
}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err

  var text = makeMessage.makeMessage(msg.text, data.user.name);
  sendMessage.send(msg, text, slack);
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and I've been working and searching on a fix for more days than I care to admit and this worked perfectly!  Thanks for posting!