# How to get actual slack username instead of user id

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I have pulled data from a private slack channel, using conversation history, and it pulls the userid instead of username, how can I change the code to pull the user name so I can identify who each user is? Code below

```
 CHANNEL = ""
MESSAGES_PER_PAGE = 200
MAX_MESSAGES = 1000
SLACK_TOKEN = ""

client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token=SLACK_TOKEN)

# get first page
page = 1
print("Retrieving page {}".format(page))
response = client.conversations_history(
    channel=CHANNEL,
    limit=MESSAGES_PER_PAGE,
)
assert response["ok"]
messages_all = response['messages']

# get additional pages if below max message and if they are any
while len(messages_all) + MESSAGES_PER_PAGE <= MAX_MESSAGES and response['has_more']:
    page += 1
    print("Retrieving page {}".format(page))
    sleep(1)   # need to wait 1 sec before next call due to rate limits
    response = client.conversations_history(
        channel=CHANNEL,
        limit=MESSAGES_PER_PAGE,
        cursor=response['response_metadata']['next_cursor']
    )
    assert response["ok"]
    messages = response['messages']
    messages_all = messages_all + messages
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get username/userID in slack bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147001/how-to-get-username-userid-in-slack-bot)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to change what is returned from the `conversations.history` method.  If you'd like to convert user IDs to usernames, you'll need to either:

1. Call the [`users.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) method and retrieve the username from the response.

or

2. Call the [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) method and iterate through the list and create a local copy (or store in a database) and then have your code look it up.

Comment: thank you!! Do you think I would need to either edit my current slack app or create a new one for this?

Comment: It's really up to you! If it were me, I'd just edit my current app but if creating a new app makes it easier for you, do that! :)